# MySql select statement with conditional where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a MySql statement with a conditional where clause.
something like this:

set @price = 5000 ;
set @city = 1324368075;

```
 select count(*)
 from property
 where case when @price is not null then
              price < @price
       end
       and (case when @city is not null then
             CityId = @city
          end)
```

the variable should be included in the query only if it is not null.

My attempts have failed so far.  Any ideas?

Edited:

Sorry I spoke too soon ysth,

these two queries are supposed to yield the same count but they dont.

[image]

[image]

Edit #2:  Execution plan & indexes

Here's the query:

```
 set @CountryId = null ;
 set  @CityId = 1324368075 ;
 set @StateProvince = null ;
 set @CategoryId = null ; 
 set  @TransactionTypeId = null;
 set @Price = 5000;
 
 SELECT 
  Count(*) 
FROM 
  meerkat.property 
WHERE 
  (CASE WHEN @CountryId IS NOT NULL THEN CountryId = @CountryId ELSE 1 END)
  AND (CASE WHEN  @CityId IS NOT NULL THEN CityId = @CityId ELSE 1 END) 
  AND (CASE WHEN @CategoryId IS NOT NULL THEN CategoryId = @CategoryId ELSE 1 END) 
  AND (CASE WHEN  @StateProvince IS NOT NULL THEN StateProvince = @StateProvince ELSE 1 END) 
  AND (CASE WHEN @TransactionTypeId IS NOT NULL THEN TransactionTypeId = @TransactionTypeId ELSE 1 END) 
  AND (CASE WHEN @Price IS NOT NULL THEN Price <= @Price ELSE 1 END) 
  AND IsPublic = 1 
  AND IsBlocked = 0;
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if its NULL, what is the expected behaviour then- select without condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no when conditions are met, `case` returns null.  If you want each test to pass, you need to return a true value instead, so:

```
case when @price is not null then
          price < @price
    else 1 end
and ...
```

Comment: I have edited my original post to share an issue I have run into ysth.  Thanks for taking another look

Comment: your revised code is doing when databasecolumn is not null.  that is very different, and the when condition will be false.

Comment: You're right! Will Fix it and try again later. Thanks

Comment: Fixed the bug. Execution time is still high though.  I have about every index possible on the table but it seems to use only one of them ( the least useful in this case).  Is there a way to force the use of a different index?

Comment: yes, you can do `from property use index (indexname)` (where  indexname is what `show create table property` shows before the list of columns indexed).  `use index` doesn't make it use that index, but basically makes it pretend all other indexes don't exist.  there's also `force index` which does the same but also makes it prefer using the index over a full table scan

Comment: you can't do that based on if a variable is null or not, though.

Comment: ok, thanks for the information.  Based on my query, what would be the best index to add to this table?

Comment: since you can't tell from the query which conditions will be checked, there is no such index.  you should make your client code construct an appropriate query for the actual case needed (e.g. `select count(*) from property where cityID=...`) and then mysql will be able to pick a good index

Comment: Ok. thanks ysth. You were incredibly helpful.